# Is there any particular way to have ViewPager as ListView item in android?

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager, listviewitem

I am trying to add viewpager in listview item. But when I scroll the listview, viewpager in all the list item went missing. I have gone through many answers and tried them. Is there any way to solve this problem? Is it possible to have viewpager as listviewitem?

**Edit** : I ended up using vertical scrollview and add multiple view pagers programmatically. And it works like a charm.

Comment: can you post a screenshot what u want

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using vertical ScrollView and add multiple view pagers programmatically. It worked like a charm!